# Creating a Dictionary from a while loop (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

How can I create a Dictionary from my while loop below? infile reads from a file called input, which has the following content:

min:1,23,62,256

max:24,672,5,23

sum:22,14,2,3,89

P90:23,30,45.23

P70:12,23,24,57,32

```
infile = open("input.txt", "r")
answers = open("output.txt", "w")

while True:
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line: break
    opType = line[0:3]
    numList = (line[4:len(line)])
    numList = numList.split(',')
```

What I'm trying to do is basically 2 lists, one that has the operation name (opType) and the other that has the numbers. From there I want to create a dictionary that looks like this

```
myDictionary = {
    'min': 1,23,62,256,
    'max': 24,672,5,23,
    'avg': 22,14,2,3,89,
    'P90': 23,30,45.23,
    'P70': 12,23,24,57,32,
}
```

The reason for this is that I need to call the operation type to a self-made function, which will then carry out the operation. I'll figure this part out. I currently just need help making the dictionary from the while loop.

I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

I believe, you would need the 'sum' also in the dictionary. If not, just add a condition to remove it.

```
myDictionary = {}
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.split(':')[1].rstrip().split(',')
        for i in xrange(len(x)):
            try:
                x[i] = int(x[i])
            except ValueError:
                x[i] = float(x[i])
        myDictionary[line.split(':')[0]] = x
print myDictionary
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. I just added orderedDict `myDictionary = {} `
`myDictionary = collections.OrderedDict()`

Comment: Thanks, can you please accept my answer as the rigt one. Your help is appreciated.